# Como tratar a orientação da tela em QML?

Tags: qt, qml

Desenvolvo normalmente focado a a orientação vertical, mas quando viro a tela do dispositivo para horizontal, o elementos são redimensionados de forma indesejada, deixando alguns menores do que realmente deveriam ser.

Por exemplo:

```qml
Rectangle
{
    id: foo
    width: parent.width * 0.8;
    height: parent.height * 0.025;
}
```

Em dispositivo de 1024 x 600, quando na vertical `foo` tem 25px de altura, mas quando na horizontal fica com 15px, o que compromete a leitura de possíveis textos dentro do `Rectangle`.

É possível fixar um tamanho mínimo para quando estiver na horizontal?
E qual a melhor forma de tratar questões orientação da tela em QML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode deduzir a orientação da tela pela proporção `width/height`. Um exemplo:

```qml
Item {
    id: root
    property int isVertical: width/height < 1

    Text {
        text: root.isVertical ? "Vertical" : "Horizontal"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Mas fazer uso de uma condicional assim pode fazer o layout não mudar fluidamente quando alguém redimencionar a janela (em desktop). Se o foco for apenas dispositivos com tamanho fixo de tela, não precisa se preocupar tanto com isso.

De qualquer forma o melhor é construir o layout para se adaptar ao tamanho de tela, seja ele qual for. Afinal você pode ter um vertical que seja bastante menor do que o esperado e o texto ficará ilegível do mesmo jeito. Defina um tamanho mínimo!

```qml
Item {
    id: root

    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "green"
        width: parent.width * 0.8
        height: Math.max(parent.height / 6, 25)
    }
}
```

Assim qualquer texto dentro do retângulo ficará sempre legível.

Comment: Só uma dúvida, o uso desse condicional pode comprometer o desempenho ou ele só é calculado quando o Rectangle é criado?

Comment: Não compromete. Todos os valores de propriedades são expressões de JavaScript que são recalculados apenas quando qualquer um dos operandos muda. É equivalente ao seu `width: parent.width * 0.8;`.